# Pre-determined message types out on key press

Tags: javascript, events, onkeypress

I have a div that is contenteditable with the id of "editable." 
I want the end result to be that a user types, but rather than the physical key event, a pre-determined message appears.

For example, if the pre-determined message is the word, "Sing", then no matter what letter the user types first, the first letter to appear is "S", on the second key press, an "i" would appear, and so on.

I've found code on this forum that simulates changing the character associated with a key event, and I've modified the code to achieve the "S" from my example.  I've pasted the code below and created it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/61/

This code, of course, gives me the "S" infinite times.  Where I'm stuck is performing this function only once, then calling another function for the "i", then the "n" and so on.
I've gotten one possible lead on a toggle function that I suppose may work, but have been unable to discern how to apply it to my code.

```
function transformTypedCharacter(charStr) {
  return /[a-z]/.test(charStr) ? "S" : /[A-Z]/.test(charStr) ? "S" :   charStr;
}

function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
  var sel, range, textNode;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      range.deleteContents();
      textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
      range.insertNode(textNode);

      // Move caret to the end of the newly inserted text node
      range.setStart(textNode, textNode.length);
      range.setEnd(textNode, textNode.length);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.pasteHTML(text);
  }
}


$("#editable").keypress(function(evt) {
  if (evt.which) {
    var charStr = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    var transformedChar = transformTypedCharacter(charStr);
    if (transformedChar != charStr) {
      insertTextAtCursor(transformedChar);
      return false;
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add your HTML, complete JS code and also mention any Library you are using like jQuery etc... it would awesome if you can create your code in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm not sure how you can expect "Sing" when your `transformTypedCharacter` function returns `S` for every alphabetical input character

Comment: Did you try to use evt.preventDefault() inside keypress handler?

Comment: Here is the code in jsfiddle.net- http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/61/

Comment: Tyler, My question is how end this function, while also triggering the next function for the next letter in my pre-determined message- in this case the next letter is first and "i", then an "n", etc.

Comment: Bergi, your observation is exactly my problem.  I don't know how to write the code to return the "S" only once, then return an "i" only once, and so on.

Comment: STO, thanks for your suggestion.  Unfortunately I'm not savvy enough to know exactly where to put your code.  I'd greatly appreciate it if you could place it in the jsfiddle.net example that I pasted into my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var list = "Sing".split('');
function transformTypedCharacter(charStr) {
    return /[a-zA-Z]/.test(charStr) ? list.shift()||" " : charStr;
}
```

However I'm not sure whether this is really the best approach, as it might be possible that `transformTypedCharacter` is not called in a linear fashion respective to the expected output string. If you hit backspace, you might return some characters twice, and if you hit umlauts etc the would be inserted somewhere in your result.

Comment: This is great!  When backspace is hit, it deletes a character, then skips on to the next character.  This issue is not important for my purposes.  My only issue is that there are no spaces possible in the output string.  "Sing" was an example, but my real output message is an entire paragraph.  Is there a fix for this?  Here is http://jsfiddle.net/Ukkmu/63/ with the output message "Sing to me." with underscores as place holders for spaces.  I could just leave it with underscores, but I'd rather not.  Thanks again.

Comment: No idea, the problem is somewhere in your `insertTextAtCursor` function